# Python Kivy graph code only gives 'Python has stopped working' as error message

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to play around with a real-time kivy graph using the `kivy_garden.graph` module. However, when i run the following code, I get no error message other than a popup stating 'Python has stopped working'. Once I press cancel on that, I get `Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`. Here's my code:

```
from math import sin
from kivy_garden.graph import Graph, MeshLinePlot
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock


class MyApp(App):
    plot = MeshLinePlot(color=[1, 0, 0, 1])

    graph = Graph(xlabel='X', ylabel='Y', x_ticks_minor=5,
        x_ticks_major=25, y_ticks_major=1,
        y_grid_label=False, x_grid_label=False, padding=5,
        x_grid=False, y_grid=False, xmin=-0, xmax=100, ymin=-1, ymax=1,)

    def build(self):

        box = BoxLayout()
        box.add_widget(self.graph)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_points, 1/60.)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_xaxis, 1/60.)

        return box

    def update_xaxis(self,*args):
        self.graph.xmin = 0
        self.graph.xmax = 100

    def update_points(self, *args):
        #self.plot.points = [(i,i)]

        self.plot.points = [(x, sin(x / 10.)) for x in range(0, 101)]





MyApp().run()
```

My other kivy apps are running just fine on the same python installation, so I'm inclined to believe that there's something wrong with my code.

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange as it may seem, it appears that your `Graph()` and `MeshLinePlot()` calls must be in the opposite order:

```
class MyApp(App):
    graph = Graph(xlabel='X', ylabel='Y', x_ticks_minor=5,
        x_ticks_major=25, y_ticks_major=1,
        y_grid_label=False, x_grid_label=False, padding=5,
        x_grid=False, y_grid=False, xmin=-0, xmax=100, ymin=-1, ymax=1,)
    plot = MeshLinePlot(color=[1, 0, 0, 1])

    def build(self):
        self.graph.add_plot(self.plot)
        box = BoxLayout()
        box.add_widget(self.graph)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_points, 1/60.)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_xaxis, 1/60.)

        return box
```

And you were missing the `self.graph.add_plot(self.plot)` line.

Answer (score 0):

#### Research

The error-code `0xC0000005` might be a *Windows related error*, known as **Access Violation**. See
[Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50620954/process-finished-with-exit-code-1073741819-0xc0000005-pycharm)

On the other side any threading-related seems suspicious.
So, searched for [`Clock.schedule_interval`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html#kivy.clock.CyClockBase.schedule_interval) and found an answer that suggested to avoid duplicate scheduling. See
[Kivy - Trying to Understand Clock.schedule_interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27027942/kivy-trying-to-understand-clock-schedule-interval).

To avoid duplicate calls, they propose to unschedule before scheduling again.

```
# First, schedule once.
event = Clock.schedule_once(my_callback, 0)

# Then, in another place you will have to unschedule first to avoid duplicate call. Then you can schedule again.
Clock.unschedule(event)
event = Clock.schedule_once(my_callback, 0)
```

I can't tell what your separately scheduled update-events are for, but it looks like they can be combined to one update-callback.